# Using an animated GIF as a symbol in QGIS

Tags: qgis-3

Is there any possibility to use an animated GIF as a symbol marker in QGIS?

I am working on real time lightening data, so I would like to make something like this: https://lyn.met.no, so far I have this: https://vimeo.com/565362710

Using a calculated virtual field, and an auto updating data set, I can update the age of the incoming data and change color of the symbol as time goes on, but I wonder if it is possible to also make the first shrinking circle animation without going into making a lot of different symbols for the first few seconds.

(I would guess that the answer to my question is "no", but I might have overlooked something...)

Answer (score 4):

Animated markers have been added in 3.26:

[image]

Source: https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog326/index.html#feature-new-animated-marker-symbol-type